# How good / healthy are the support resources / forums and communities around Kafka VS RabbitMQ VS SQS?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, apache-kafka, amazon-sqs

On behalf of my company I'm currently evaluating three Message-oriented middleware technologies: Kafka, RabbitMQ and SQS.

Could someone please give me a hint on how good/healthy the support & help resources, forums and communities are around Kafka VS RabbitMQ VS SQS?

I want to ensure that the technology we choose has a healthy community and that it is easy to get help and search forums to find information related to troubleshooting, operations and optimisation.

Comment: Such kind of questions are off-topic on SO. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0):

SQS is an amazon product, so it comes with the usual AWS support: good support if you pay, poor support if you don't.
That being say, SQS is not really like Kafka. If you want the AWS equivalent of Kafka, you should probably consider Amazon Kinesis instead of SQS. (difference between Kinesis and SQS: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Kinesis-and-SQS-It-seems-capable-of-serving-similar-use-cases-apart-from-the-shards-and-partition-keys)

Kafka is open source and actively developed (mostly by engineers from LinkedIn). The mailing list is active, and most of the questions are answered quickly. If you are in the bay area, LinkedIn is regularly organizing meetups, so you can exchange with the committers/other companies using Kafka. There are also a few Kafka meetup groups in other cities.
Kafka is used by a wide range of companies (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Powered+By). Most of the issues you would be encountering would have already been encountered by someone else. So it's rather easy to just use google to get answers to your questions.

I don't know about RabbitMQ.